# Geb - getting "No at checker has been defined for page class geb.Page."

Tags: automated-testing, appium, cucumber, geb

Does anyone have any experience with using Geb and Cucumber in testing Native Apps?

Trying to figure out why I cant use the Geb Page object in my tests. Seems to time out on me and throw the following ...

```
Caused by: geb.error.UndefinedAtCheckerException: No at checker has been defined for page class geb.Page.
    at geb.Page.verifyThisPageAtOnly(Page.groovy:231)
    at geb.Page.verifyAt(Page.groovy:182)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:207)
    at com.pages.Workflows$_navigate_closure1$_closure3.doCall(Workflows.groovy:29)
    at com.pages.Workflows$_navigate_closure1$_closure3.doCall(Workflows.groovy)
    at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:127)
    at geb.waiting.Wait$waitFor.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.waiting.DefaultWaitingSupport.doWaitFor(DefaultWaitingSupport.groovy:51)
    at geb.waiting.DefaultWaitingSupport.this$2$doWaitFor(DefaultWaitingSupport.groovy)
    at geb.waiting.DefaultWaitingSupport.waitFor(DefaultWaitingSupport.groovy:38)
    at geb.waiting.WaitingSupport$waitFor.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Page.waitFor(Page.groovy:506)
    at geb.Page.waitFor(Page.groovy)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:207)
    at geb.Browser.invokeMethod(Browser.groovy)
    at com.pages.Workflows$_navigate_closure1.doCall(Workflows.groovy:29)
    at com.pages.Workflows$_navigate_closure1.doCall(Workflows.groovy)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1047)
    at geb.Browser$drive$1.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1017)
    at geb.Browser$drive$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.pages.Workflows.navigate(Workflows.groovy:27)
    at com.pages.Workflows$navigate.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.stepDefs.LoginPageSteps$_run_closure3.doCall(LoginPageSteps.groovy:51)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyBackend.invoke(GroovyBackend.java:155)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyStepDefinition$1.call(GroovyStepDefinition.java:71)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.groovy.GroovyStepDefinition.execute(GroovyStepDefinition.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:121)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Thus may be a result of how I am implementing this?

Comment: Could you please update your question with your test code? That might give people a better idea of the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with your page object and use of "at" in the steps file.
Lets say your **Page object** is `HomePage`

Do you have a step that begins with "at" like:

```
{
Given (~/I go to the HomePage/) ->
    at HomePage
    ...
}
```

And
Do you have the following in your HomePage page object ?

```
static at = { $('title').text() == "Title of Page" }
```

If you use "at" in your step but don't have is defined in the page object, you'll get that error.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/browser.html

Pages define an “at checker” that the browser uses for checking if it is pointing at a given page.

```
class SignupPage extends Page {
    static at = {
        $("h1").text() == "Signup Page"
    }
}

Browser.drive {
    to SignupPage
}
```